# NGINX - return 301 keeps redirecting to HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

I have the following configuration:

```
server{ 
  ssl on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...
  location = / {
    return 301 https://$host/appName;
  }
  location = /appName {
    ...
    proxy_pass $some_internal_server;
    ...
  }
}
```

When I type in a browser ***https***://my_url I'm redirected to ***http***://my_url/appName instead of ***https***://my_url/appName

How can I fix this?

Comment: 301 is browser cache, add a 301 on http back to https

Comment: @JacobEvans Adding redirect from http to https is a successful workaround. While it is being a successful trick, I don't understand why it does happen in the first place. Cache cannot be blamed, since http was never enabled on this server.

Comment: Sure, you positive you didn't typo your 301 to http once?...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix a 301 is another 301.

> 301 is browser cache, add a 301 on http back to https

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the top of the file, before anything, the following:

```
server  {
        listen  80;
        server_name my_url;

        return  301     https://$server_name;
}
```

Also I would change your

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://$host/appName;
  }
```

to

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://$server_name/appName;
  }
```

Comment: `https://$server_name$request_uri;`